# how to store values in boost::any map

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a std::string in map and getting the following error
`error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::any&’ from expression of type ‘std::string’`

the code is as follows

```
#include "boost/any.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string, boost::any> m;

void putObject(string name, boost::any& value)
{ m[name]= value; }

boost::any getObject(string name) { return m[name]; }

int main()
{
    string s = "a";
    cout << "Original Address: " << &s << endl;

    putObject(s, s);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: you need to have putObject take the boost::any by const reference or by value to allow the implicit conversion to happen.

Comment: non-const references can only bind to lvalues, and the result of the string -> boost::any implicit conversion is not an lvalue. It's just a rule of the language.

Comment: @Jimm: by taking a non-const reference, you imply you want to change the caller's variable... if an implicit conversion had already kicked in for that variable, then you'd be changing a temporary - it'd be a sometimes-subtle and easily made mistake that'd cause a lot of grief.  Therefore the Standard doesn't allow it.  Anyway, you should be using `const` just because you're only reading from value... the signature of `putObject` is actively confusing.